# Elevate zoom not compatible with image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble implementing elevate zoom with an image map, the hover magnifier just seems to cover up the image map..

my code

```
     <div id="zoom_06">

    <img class="front-div" id="zoom_01" src='stoneybrae_overallsiteplan.jpg' data-zoom-image="stoneybrae-devmap580.jpg" usemap="#testmap200" />

    <map name="testmap200" id="testmap200">
    <area shape="rect" coords="1,1,550,625" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">
    </map>

    </div>

    </body>

   <script>

    $("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({
   cursor: "crosshair"
    });
   </script>
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

Thanks!